# certificate-manager 'lstool reregister' failed | SSL Certificate Issue

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I have been trying to get this to work for some days now, have installed fresh numerous times, it just won't work.

vCenter Appliance version is 6.7.0 build-16709110 (6.7 U3 J, tried latest version U3 L as well), changed browser as well none of it helped.

Once vCenter is installed I am only able to login once, the 1st time, and thats it. Once the vCenter is restarted the HTML UI shows

> Failed to connect to VMware Lookup Service - SSL Certificate Verification Failed

I have tried Reset All Certifications (option 8 in Certificate Manager) which was successful but upon vCenter restart the same error again.

I have attached the log, and screenshot, if someone can help as this has been going on for days now trying to troubleshooting one method after another from kb.vmware.com.

I attempted a CA certificate using option 1 in Certificate manager and using the CSR to get the certificate from Windows Server CA (no intermediate CA) but that method as instructed on https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2112014 does not work either.

https://justpaste.it/33hi7

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching I finally found the answer to this issue.

A file in the vCenter shell needs editing to fix this issue of being able to replace certificates in case of this type of error.

Explained here https://mueller-tech.com/2019/06/28/replacing-expired-certificates/

I managed to get the vCenter up and running, and even restarted and checked, working fine.